# Where to find Sitefinity version compatible with ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: content-management-system, telerik, sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I could only find links to Sitefinity 4.0 on Telerik's website.  Where can I find a 3.5 compatible version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitefinity 4.0 is only compatible with asp.net 4.0.

If you previously purchased 3.x and are wanting to redownload it, it should be under your Sitefinity account under "older versions" on the download products page.

hope this was helpful!

Comment: Do they have the community editions of the 3.x versions available?

Comment: I'd recommend you contact Sitefinity support on getting access to previous versions of SF. However, 4 does also have a free Community version available as well.